# Regex that matches either float or interger which may be either positive or negative

Tags: regex

Let say I have the following string which consists of integer and float numbers , which may be positive or negative.

```
valueA:112,valueB:06                                                                 
valueC:446977                                                                                                 
valueD:0.0                                                                                                   
valueE:-102.4,valueF:-15.7                                                  
valueG:9.8
```

So far with the help of https://regex101.com/ I have reached to the following regex :

```
-?\d+(\.-?\d+)?
```

I have managed to extract all numbers both integer and float , both positive and negative.

However there is one drawback for the case of float numbers.
The full match equals the whole float number correctly but in Group1 it also returns a string which consists of the decimal point and the decimals of the number.

E.x for the case for -102.4 the full match returns the string -102.4 whereas Group 1 returns the string .4.

What should I change on the above regex in order not to return these Group1 strings and just return the Full matches of the numbers?

Comment: What is the meaning of the hyphen before the decimal part? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: I'd use `-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use:

```
-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/hqdKqk/1)

Comment: Minor tweak to add support for a positive sign: `[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?`

Comment: Note that this answer does not pass 5. (Five Dot).  You need to add alternation to be able to pass decimal points with either nothing before or nothing after.